# Complete CSV not imported Successfully

Tags: php, csv, import, codeigniter-3, import-csv

I am importing CSV file in CI 3 with the following script, but it import partially, Not import all rows in csv are importing.

```
$content = $this->csv_reader->parse_file($_FILES['products']['tmp_name']);
//print_r($content);
if (count($content) > 0) {
    function clean($string) {
       //$string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
    
       return preg_replace('/[^ .@A-Za-z0-9\-\&\,\']/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
    }
    foreach ($content as $csv_arr) {
        
        $insert_csv_arr = array(
            
            'brand_name' => clean(rtrim($csv_arr['BrandName'])),
            'keyword' => clean(rtrim($csv_arr['keyword'])),
            'amz_sold_by' => clean(rtrim($csv_arr['amzsoldby'])),
            'seller_code' => clean(rtrim($csv_arr['SellerCode'])),
            'product_link' => clean(rtrim($csv_arr['productlink'])),
            'asin' => clean(rtrim($csv_arr['asin'])),
            
        );
        //print_r($insert_csv_arr); die();
        $this->productmodel->insert($insert_csv_arr);   
    }
```

I also increase the time using `set_time_limit` but it is not working.

For example i have a sheet of 465 products but imports only 161 products.

**I want to know what are the possible reasons that CSV is not imported completely ?**

Comment: What is your PHP max execution time set to?

Comment: We know that the script is halting, so if you comment out your insert and uncomment the preceding print_r statement, do you get all 465 entries. Then inspect row 162 as it might be blowing things up. Also look in your error logs.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw in print_r only row is printed...not all

Comment: @HamzaZafeer Sorry my bad - you need to do that outside of the foreach loop to inspect the total rows read and so you can view them.

Comment: @HamzaZafeer Did you check your error logs?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw outside of the loop it prints only last row of the sheet

Comment: @HamzaZafeer (note to self) Number 1 rule - dont answer questions when half asleep... Ok. What I am trying to get you to do is to create an array with all results without doing the insert. I am expecting something might be causing the loop to break due to an error. While it's simple to do, it's obviously hard to explain... Try changing $insert_csv_arr = array( to $insert_csv_arr[] = array( which will build an array with all entries...

Comment: @TimBrownlaw it prints all rows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235654/discussion-between-timbrownlaw-and-hamza-zafeer).

Answer (score 0):

`ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');` // for infinite time of execution

use this code in your function on top

Comment: That is a bad idea. It's better to discover why it's taking so long ( if that is what is happening - we do not know) than just let it run forever.